# What is difference between bundled product and configurable product in magento?

Tags: magento

What is difference, programmatically, between bundled product and configurable product in magento?  What can one do that the other can't?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A configurable product is a number of different but related items in which the user selects one of them by choosing a series of options. For example, a T-shirt could have many different sizes. Each size is a different physical unit but the customer just goes to the T-shirt page and then selects a size.

A bundled product would be a group of items grouped together, like a kit, that sell as a single unit. For example, I might have a fishing rod and a fishing reel that sell separately, but I also bundle them together as a combo.

Comment: I accept the answer can u check my other question creating a product from frontend.

Comment: what u think about it creating a product from frontend.